# What causes SignalR to receive net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on connect?

Tags: signalr

I have a simple SingulaR example that I've added to a legacy ASP.Net MVC application.

Here are the various parts:

**OWIN Startup class**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof (Startup))]

namespace MyApp.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

**SignalR Hub**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace MyApp.Web
{
    [HubName("podService")]
    public class PodServiceHub : Hub
    {
        public PodServiceHub()
        {
            ;
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetMessages()
        {
            return new[] {"blah", "blah", "blah"};
        }
    }
}
```

**Server-side facade**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace MyApp.Web
{
    public class PodService
    {
        PodService(IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> clients)
        {
            Clients = clients;
        }

        public PodService()
            : this(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PodServiceHub>().Clients)
        {
        }

        IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> Clients { get; set; }

        public void SendMessageToClient(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.doSomething(message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Portions of startup Javascript:**

```
    var podService = $.connection.podService;

...



    $.extend(podService.client, {
        doSomething: function(message) {
            console.log("received message:" + message);
        }
    });


    // test
    $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function() {
            podService.server.getMessages()
                .done(function(messages) {
                    console.log("received message:" + message);
                });
        });
```

Within one of the controllers called by the first page:

```
_podService.SendMessageToClient("Hello from the server!");
```

Upon executing the application, the following error is displayed in the console of Chrome's dev tools:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:62025/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=02LJFqBcRBWKXAOlaSwgMPWG0epV7AFl19gNjFCvA0dxD2QH8%2BC9V028Ehu8fYAFN%2FthPv65JZKfK2MgCEdihCJ0A2dMyENOcdPkhDzEwNB2WQ1X4QXe1fiZAyMbkZ1b&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22podservice%22%7D%5D&tid=6' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

After this error, however, the podService.server.getMessages() returns with the message from the server printing ["blah", "blah", "blah"] to the console and subsequently the doSomething client function is invoked printing "received message: Hello from the server!".

The calls from both the client and the server are transmitting data, so this error doesn't appear to be breaking the app.  It definitely seems to be an issue though.  The code above was based upon the sample code generated by the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Sample NuGet package which doesn't display the same behavior.  The only difference I'm aware of between my example and NuGet-based sample is that I've added this to a legacy MVC app vs. a pure OWIN-based app.  Based upon a comment I read [on this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273700/signalr-without-owin) this shouldn't be an issue.

So, what's wrong with this example usage and/or what could be causing the connection reset?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to your problem? I'm facing the same...

Answer (score 22):

I made sure:

1. [the web socket component is enabled in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30600999/818321)
2. [and the "allowKeepAlive" setting is not set to false in my web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34611101/818321)

But in my case the problem was caused by a packages version mismatch:
In the packages.config Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb version 2.1.0 was referenced accidentally

```
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```

While all the other Owin related packages were referencing version 3.0.1
I updated Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb to version 3.0.1

Then I had to make sure in the web.config file the "httpRuntime" element targeted the framework version 4.5

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
```

The two steps above solved the problem.

Comment: Props to @Nik, the httpRuntime did it for me!

Comment: If none of these help, check if your site is behind a reverse proxy and test a direct connection if possible. In my case, SignalR websockets work with a direct connection, but the reverse proxy breaks them.

Comment: <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" /> solved my problem

Comment: That was awesome ,Thank you so mush man you saved about a day for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran in to this one myself. In my case the answer seems to be enabling WebSockets for IIS.

[Enable WebSockets in IIS 8.0](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support#TOC301258517)

It works because signalR falls back to one of the following depending on the capabilities of the browser and server.

- Server Sent Events.
- Forever Frame
- AJAX Long Polling

For more information on the transports used and their fallbacks see [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr#transports)

Comment: I'm guessing this isn't the case in my case since both the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Sample package project as well as the project I had this in were both using IIS Express, but only my code manifested this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to remove

```
<httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="false" />
```

from our web.config (it was there for historical reasons).

Comment: I didn't had this element in the web.config. However, it was in the parent web site's config. Removing it helped.

Answer (score 0):

In my Case I was using

```
string sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GAFI_SignalR"].ConnectionString;
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString);
```

The problem was accessing the database when the user didin't have permission to connect to the database.