# SignalR - Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 504

Tags: javascript, signalr, signalr.client

I'm trying to connect with signalr hub, but I'm getting the following error in javascript:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://dev:777/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=%2BRUC9XodaU4R3Wn3BSLfhZXxLqeLj9fp4XlLJSsxrc36dFuEo6O9GOIGYMdsgSeswY2DTzzJe9qCe9JnqgjwusbYROxjkY%2B6d9FD4MVpox4FLEqNzCF5Y%2BOqrY5ndNs%2FRl7aOoKIYelpGmerXj4mdw%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22machinehub%22%7D%5D&tid=5' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 504
```

and then in console

```
Could not connect. Invocation of StartMachine failed. Error: No transport could be initialized successfully. Try specifying a different transport or none at all for auto initialization.
```

I'm using such code to invoke my method from hub which:

```
 self.Run = function (action, parameters, callbacks) {
    try {
        var connection = $.hubConnection();
        connection.logging = self.Debug;
        var hub = connection.createHubProxy(self.Name);

        registerConnectionEvents(connection);
        registerEvents(hub, callbacks);

        connection.start({ transport: ['webSockets'] })
            .done(function () {
                self.debug("Now connected!");

                hub.invoke.apply(hub, $.merge([action], parameters)).fail(function (error) {
                    var msg = 'Invocation of ' + action + ' failed. ' + error;
                    self.debug(msg);
                });                   
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                var msg = 'Could not connect. Invocation of ' + action + ' failed. ' + error;
            self.debug(msg);
        });

        return true;
    }
```

When I run my MVC5 app with signalr in Visual Studio everything is fine. After publication to IIS8 on windows Server 2012 it can't connect over web sockets in signal r. I tried to turn off both firewalls for testing but with no success. Can you help me resolve that issue? Of course I read everthing on that page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/

Answer (score 2):

In order for SignalR to work properly with WebSocket, you must be sure both client and server support WebSocket. If testing locally works fine, then your browser probably already supports it.

Windows Server 2012 supports SignalR, but you need to be sure websockets feature is enabled:

[image]

If this is already enabled, then try recycling your Application Pool (or resetting the IIS).

---

If recycling/resetting is not sufficient, then you might have something else between the server and the client, like a **proxy server** or another security layer, like a network firewall (which you might don't have access to it), it could exist in an enterprise environment, or in servers hosted in places like Amazon which might be blocking a port.

Comment: I have installed  WebSocket Protocol but my signal r works only in generatd proxy with long pooling. I don't know why websocket is being reset.

Comment: @MarekBar what browser are you using? After installing websocket did you try restarting the server? It shouldn't be necessary, but we never know...

Comment: See the thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/37531108/2416627 for some additional prerequisites. In particular, `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />` seems to be necessary in the Web.config file.

Comment: This worked for me. I was getting 400 bad response format exception. After installing Websocket protocol, it worked for me

Comment: @ShahidIqbal that's nice to hear, consider upvoting the answer :)