# Signalr net:: Error connection_reset

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I'm working with a web app based on signalr platform and the page works fine the most of the time. I have made it based on hubs methods in an infinite loop where I receive messages. The problem is I want the website to work 24/7 and in one day I had an error in my console saying: net::CONNECTION_RESSET
 this is the full error: [Error conection resset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSB13.png)

and in this moment I got logged out and I stopped receiving messages.
Now my question is: 
Is this a chrome related bug or a signalr related?
How can I resolve this?

Edit: 
After occurring on this problem added in my js code:

```
 $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if ($.connection.hub.lastError) {
                console.log("Disconnected. Reason: " + 
                 $.connection.hub.lastError.message);
            } else {
                console.log("Disconnected");
            }
            $.connection.hub.start();
        }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
    });
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37531108/87514

Comment: Depends on the transport mechanism and whether the app went Idle. Personally you should fire off an event to reconnect on disconnection and allow to keep the connection alive.

Comment: @TezWingfield hello atter occurring this problem on my js code I'v added : 
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if ($.connection.hub.lastError) {
                console.log("Disconnected. Reason: " + $.connection.hub.lastError.message);
            } else {
                console.log("Disconnected");
            }
            $.connection.hub.start();
        }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
    });

Comment: Can you update the question with code?

Comment: @TezWingfield Updated!

Comment: @Anonymuslegacy Sorry, I didn't mean the "updated code". I mean the Hub and accompanying js.