# SignalR WebSockets work locally but not on server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, websocket, signalr

I'm trying to get Web Sockets working as the protocol with an ASP.NET 4.8 Framework app that uses SignalR 2.4.2. It works fine with Visual Studio 2019 on localhost, running Windows 10 Pro. It fails on a Windows 2016 server (not Azure) with this error in Chrome 85:

> signalr?v=igzza46L1gfiUBzl96WDUmuI9_CUHV_qqd0Kd-fDr8A1:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://someServer.org/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=2.1&connectionToken=...&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22myhub%22%7D%5D&tid=0' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

and

```
No transport could be initialized successfully. Try specifying a different transport or none at all for auto initialization.
  at Object.error (signalr?vv=...:1)
  at g (signalr?vv=...:1)
  at v (signalr?vv=...:1)
  at h.transportFailed (signalr?vv=...:1)
  at signalr?vv=...:1
  at WebSocket.e.socket.e.socket.onclose (signalr?vv=...:1)
```

Opening this URL on the server `https://myserver.org/signalr/negotiate` to get the SignalR details produces the following:

```
Url "/signalr"
ConnectionToken "..."
ConnectionId    "..."
KeepAliveTimeout    20
DisconnectTimeout   30
ConnectionTimeout   110
TryWebSockets   true
ProtocolVersion "1.2"
TransportConnectTimeout 5
LongPollDelay   0
```

Here's the chain of console responses in Firefox for the failed call:

```
SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'myhub'. 
SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=2.1&connectionToken=...&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22myhub%22%7D%5D'. 
SignalR: webSockets transport starting. 
SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'wss://myServer.org/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=2.1&connectionToken=...%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22myhub%22%7D%5D&tid=8'
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://myServer.org/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=2.1&connectionToken=...&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22myhub%22%7D%5D&tid=8.
SignalR: Websocket closed. 
SignalR: Closing the Websocket. 
SignalR: webSockets transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back. 
SignalR: No fallback transports were selected. 
SignalR: Stopping connection. 
SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = true.
```

WebSockets has been installed on the server using these instructions:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/websocket#windows-server-2012-or-windows-server-2012-r2
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/websocket#how-to-configure-websocket

On the client, it's using the following:

```
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['webSockets'] })
   .done(function () {
    // ...
   }).fail(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });;
```

In addition, BrowserLink is disabled in Visual Studio, as that's been mentioned as a possible cause of issues.

Additional articles researched:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37531108/177416
- https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3148

Some suggested removing the `Application_PreSendRequestHeaders` from `Global.asax.cs` but this didn't change anything on the server.

I'm aware that SignalR supports other protocols but I'm trying to get Web Sockets working.

Thanks.

**Update:** The web sockets protocol also works on the localhost of the server itself, logging in via RDP and using a browser to open the page.

Comment: What kind of certificate are you using?

Comment: Hi @LexLi, it has a self-signed certificate, and on the server, accessing localhost, it gives a warning in the browser when navigating to the site: `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

Comment: Browsers reject self-signed certificates in many ways, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1187666

Comment: Thanks, @LexLi. I think you're right; hadn't thought of it being a browser issue but it makes sense: it's not an issue on the server itself nor on localhost; only when we communicate from a browser to the server remotely. I'm going to see if our admins can replace the cert with a good one and see how that goes. In the meantime, please throw your thoughts in an answer and I'll give you credit :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a tough nut to crack. Working with the system admins, we discovered it was caused by the load balance/proxy level, which sits in front of all our traffic. By default, it didn't support web sockets. Once web sockets were enabled, SignalR was happy.

Comment: any config to get me through this. thnx

Comment: @H.Sarxha, chat with your system admins and operations people about the load balancer you're using and changing its settings