# Failed to start the connection: Error: WebSocket failed to connect

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr

> Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: WebSocket failed to
> connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the
> endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not
> present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you
> have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.
>
> WebSocketTransport.js:49 WebSocket connection to
> 'ws://xxxxxx/production/web-services/hubs/spreadhub' failed:

Angular.ts

```
 ngOnInit(): void {

      // For signalR Hub connection
      this.connection  = new HubConnectionBuilder()  
      .withUrl('http://xxx.xxx.com/production/web-services/hubs/spreadhub', {  // localhost from **AspNetCore3.1 service**
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
      })  
      .build();

        this.connection.on('dataReceived', (data: string) => {
          var model = JSON.parse(data);

      });
  
      this.connection.start().then(() => { // to start the server
             console.log('server connected!!!');
         }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

Comment: where did you run this? On linux or windows? I also face the same problem. I'm on httpd and kestrel. I think it has to do with web socket connection not allowed in httpd or forwarded to kestrel.

Comment: windows platform

Comment: For me, the issue was that our traffic sits behind a proxy which was causing issues. This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68732723/8644294

Answer (score 13):

1. Navigate to Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off (left side of the screen).
2. Open the following nodes: Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Application Development Features.
3. Select the WebSocket Protocol feature. Select OK.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to specify the full url, just the hub you want to connect to... Assuming your hub name is spreadhub you just need:

```js
this.connection  = new HubConnectionBuilder()  
    .withUrl('https://localhost:5001/spreadhub', {  // localhost from **AspNetCore3.1 service**
    skipNegotiation: true,
    transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
    })  
    .build();
```

On the server, if deployed to azure, don't forget to turn on websockets like:

[image: Configuration]

Comment: local service working fine ourside. Issue occur in online service

Answer (score 3):

There have been few cases I've got this error with no further details of the reason.

I could find some solutions to some of the problems I encountered by digging around.

- Excluding `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` in the server side of SignalR (C#). (**Beware that this is not an appropriate solution in production.**) This is often needed in your development environment.
- Invalid/expired `access token`. The `AuthenticationSchemes` needed to be defined in the `Authorize` attribute in the Hub class.

code:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class HubBase : Hub
{ }
```

- Sending the token by `accessTokenFactory` in the client side.

code:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("http://localhost:5001/hub", {
      skipNegotiation: true,
      transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
      //Adding this line
      accessTokenFactory: async () => { return this.token}
    })
    .build();
```

`this.token` is the token that you generate/fetch and send with the request.

Answer (score 1):

We have figured out there is one more case for this exception if one uses negotiate with a redirect url (as e.g. common with `Azure SignalR Service`).

If it takes few seconds between the call to the negotiate url and the redirect url returned by negotiate, we get this/similar error message. The reason I assume is that `Azure SignalR Service` does not allow for a long time window after backend communication for the client to connect.

The reason why it did take few seconds even though it should connect at once was for us that javascript thread switched to do some heavy updates of DOM and did not execute the next call right away.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `createProxyMiddleware` don't forget to include `ws: true`:

```
const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
    target: 'https://localhost:7288',
    secure: false,
    ws: true
});
```

I used Visual Studio's templates to generate ASP.NET Core + React application, it automatically included `createProxyMiddleware` inside `setupProxy.js` file

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by program restrictions on utilizing JWT with WebSockets/ServerSentEvents.
Solution to this problem

```
.AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
        {
            configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
            configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            configureOptions.SaveToken = true;
            configureOptions.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context =>
                {
                    var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                    var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken)
                        && path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs/spreadhub"))
                    {
                        context.Token = accessToken;
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
```