# NancyFX Self Host + SignalR + .Net Framework 4.0

Tags: .net, signalr, nancy, self-hosting

Is it possible to use SignalR in NancyFx using Nancy.Hosting.Self and .Net Framework 4.0 only in a Windows Service project? I usually found solutions that uses Owin and they have to target Framework 4.5.

Comment: It is very likely to be "impossible". SignalR was designed with Microsoft's Owin (Katana) in mind, so it won't work natively on Nancy's bits.

Comment: Might be, might not be... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273700/signalr-without-owin

Comment: I just upgraded to .Net Framework 4.5 and used SignalR 2.0+ instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and I do use it. You have to use [version 1.2.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR/1.2.2) as well as the version 1.2.x libraries (signalr system web and JavaScript).

You host your NancyFx as usual, and you'll find there are subtle differences in the signalr API from the current versions.